# syslog messages coming from HP switches cannot be filtered correctly in syslog-NG?

Tags: filter, syslog, syslog-ng

i am having some trouble filtering messages coming from a few sources (HP Switches) and i would like to have some advices.

i have a huge syslog-NG configuration file, filtering messages coming from many different sources (Unix servers, NAS filers, appliances, etc.)

i generally filter messages using the host() function, or filter(), or even program().

however, i am having trouble filtering messages coming from some HP switches (network & san switches), while the message format seem to be correct.

example, i'm receiving messages such as :

```
Mar 14 10:40:48 switchname program: message contents here
```

and i created a filter like this (used in a log function later):

```
filter f_network {
    host("switch*");
};
```

but it does not work (while all others are working, for other kind of devices)
i also tried to filter on the program name, same problem.

is there a way to investigate on this and understand why it is not working ?
maybe the message is formatted differently and the host field is not this one (i tried all the other fields and didn't manage to make it work)

when sniffing the network interface using tcpdump, i can see a normal message (no special characters hidden or other, apparently, but maybe i'm not using the right flags)

any way of checking this ?

thanks
regards

Comment: Hi, it seems that the Priority (PRI) value is missing from the beginning of the message. AFAIK, it should look something like this:

Comment: Hi, it seems that the Priority (PRI) value is missing from the beginning of the message. AFAIK, it should look something like this:
  <133>Feb 25 14:09:07 webserver syslogd: restart.

Can you use a dummy destination to check the values of the syslog-ng macros when reading such a message? Something like: 

destination d_file {
    file ("/var/log/messages" template("pri=${priority} date=${ISODATE} host=${HOST} program=${PROGRAM} message=${MSG}\n") );
};

If the problem is that the macro values are mismatched, then your switch is not formatting the messages correctly.

Comment: thank you robert, i will try that and let you know what it displayed ! that's the kind of thing i was looking for (the template that is).
what happens if the message does not have a good format ? will it be processed with shifted fields ? or not processed at all ?

Comment: Hi, it depends on how badly the message is broken. If only the PRI field is missing, I guess that the fields will be shifted, and possibly some of them contain invalid values (garbage). If you can verify that this is the problem, we'll find out how to solve it (as a first try, probably using the flags(no-parse) option).

Comment: hi Robert, I just made other checks and kinda understand why it's not working, depending on the switches I have multiple kind of messages.
I tried your command and it didn't log anything, so I suppose syslog-ng isn't even parsing the message ! 
I sniffed the interface agan and I can see this log for example, where fields are messed up : 
<190>raslogd: 2017/03/08-16:03:20, [SEC-1203], 53642, WWN 10:00:50:eb:1a:6c:21:38 | FID 128, INFO, cswc-mo8x-SAN01, Login information: Login successful via TELNET/SSH/RSH. IP Addr: 1.2.3.4
is there a way to have this log filtered then ?

Comment: it is surprising, if I just use a regular file as destination, I can see the message in it, if I use the template, it doesn't log anything.

eg if I use :

destination d_INCOMING_ALL       { file("/app/syslog-ng/logs/incoming_all.log"); };

I see in the file :

Mar  9 09:44:20 cswc-mo8x-hpsan01 raslogd: 2017/03/09-08:34:50, [SEC-1203], 53647, WWN 10:00:50:eb:1a:6c:21:38 | FID 128, INFO, cswc-mo8x-SAN01, Login information: Login successful via TELNET/SSH/RSH. IP Addr: 1.2.3.4

while if I use your template, I don't see any message logged from that device

Comment: I made another topic, much more clear, as the problem is kind different to what I was saying in this one (you answered for this one, so i'll consider this one as solved) : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42692552/unable-to-filter-badly-formatted-messages-in-syslog-ng

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this problem is solved somehow (because of the priority).

I made a new topic here for another error I get with a more complex syslog message : [unable to filter badly-formatted messages in syslog-ng](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42692552/unable-to-filter-badly-formatted-messages-in-syslog-ng)