# unable to filter badly-formatted messages in syslog-ng

Tags: switch-statement, syslog, syslog-ng, san

I am contacting you regarding an issue I have with syslog-NG.
some of our devices (mainly HP switches and SANs) are sending syslog messages that do not respect the syslog RFC 5424 it seems.

to give you a few examples :

if I sniff the network interface of the server, we can see these "wrong" messages like that (as you can see, after the PRI, we can see the PROGRAM, then timezone and fields separated with commas. in short, mixed fields, missing fields etc. not a standard syslog message) :

```
<190>raslogd: 2017/03/08-16:03:20, [SEC-1203], 53642, WWN 10:00:50:eb:1a:6c:21:38 | FID 128, INFO, cswc-mo8x-SAN01, Login information: Login successful via TELNET/SSH/RSH. IP Addr: 1.2.3.4
```

therefore, I am currently unable to filter these messages.
I tried to define a regular filter and try to print fields such as MSGHDR, MSG, PRI etc.. but couldn't see anything.

the ONLY WAY of having this message filtered is by just defining the external interface, and a file as output, without any template.

e.g if I do a filter like this :

```
destination d_INCOMING_ALL   { file("/app/syslog-ng/logs/incoming_all.log"); };

log {
  source(s_EXTERNAL);
  destination(d_INCOMING_ALL);
};
```

I can see messages in the log file, but formatted, somehow (I suppose syslog-NG reformats them) :

```
[root@xxxxxxxxxxxx logs]# grep -i cswc incoming_all.log
Mar  9 09:44:20 cswc-mo8x-hpsan01 raslogd: 2017/03/09-08:34:50, [SEC-1203], 53647, WWN 10:00:50:eb:1a:6c:21:38 | FID 128, INFO, cswc-mo8x-SAN01, Login information: Login successful via TELNET/SSH/RSH. IP Addr: 1.2.3.4
[root@xm1p1034vmo logs]#
```

the problem is that I cannot filter these messages like that (we receive logs from more than 1000 devices)
there, i need to filter messages coming from these devices ! 
and the only way I can do it is on the hostname (cswc-*) or program name (raslogd*)

so I tried to display the fields by adding a template to that file, example :

```
destination d_test { 
    file ("/app/syslog-ng/logs/test_olivier.log" 
    template("pri=${priority} date=${ISODATE} host=${HOST} program=${PROGRAM} message=${MSG}\n") 
    ); 
};
```

but nothing works, nothing is displayed.
I tried all fields, MSG, MESSAGE, MSGHDR etc.. can't manage do display ANYTHING.
the only working thing is the parsing without filters or templates.

naturally, if I tred all kind of filters, like these below, it does not work (as fields are mixed) :

```
filter f_is_SAN     {
    host("cswc.*" flags(ignore-case));
};
```

same for :

```
filter f_is_SAN     {
    match(".*cswc.*" flags(ignore-case));
};
```

any hints on how I create filters for these messages coming from these devices (on hostname or programname) ?

thanks
regards,

Comment: Hi, try to send the problematic messages to a separate port on your syslog-ng server, and use the no-parse flag in the source:

source { network(ip(X.X.X.X) port(X) transport("tcp") flags(no-parse)); };

This will cause syslog-ng to add a header to the message, and include everything from the message (inlcuding the original header) in the $MESSAGE macro, and set the HOST field ot the IP address of the sender.

To avoid using a separate port, use junctions: https://www.balabit.com/documents/syslog-ng-ose-latest-guides/en/syslog-ng-ose-guide-admin/html/junctions.html

Comment: hi Robert, thanks for the tip, I will try that & give you a feedback

Comment: mmh I cannot use another port, the HP switch does not support it :(

Comment: i currently just use udp(); as a source
if i use udp(flags(no-parse)); instead, will it work ? and will it block all my other filters ? (or change something in the messages behavior ?)

Comment: It will work, but will kill every other filter that you have for messages coming to that source. If such switches are the only devices that use UDP, then it's not a problem (you can have two sources on the same port, one for UDP, one for TCP. If there are other devices using UDP as well, then the only option I can think of is to use junctions in your syslog-ng configuration.

Comment: thanks Robert, i tried the no-parse option on a standalone syslog-NG server but wasn't able to print anything using the $MESSAGE macro anyway, so it doesn't work. i will have a look at these junctions, and see how i can use them, thanks for the tip !
it is frustrating to see the messages in the incoming log (i keep a copy of all logs, not applying any filters), but not being able to filter them :(

Comment: it's funny, just read that in the Junctions documentation you gave me : "For example, suppose that you have a single network source that receives log messages from different devices, and some devices send messages that are not RFC-compliant (some routers are notorious for that)." i will definitely look at that :)

Answer (score 0):

mmh thanks Robert, i tried with a single junction like this, and it works ! (it works even without the junction)
unfortunately, my other filters are not working anymore (I'm just showing 1 here, but i have more than 20, original file is much bigger)

can't we listen on two sources using the same port, but with differents flags ? :(

```
source s_EXTERNAL {
    udp();
};

source s_EXTERNAL_NOPARSE {
    udp(flags(no-parse) persist-name('noparse'));
};

destination d_INCOMING_ALL { file("/app/syslog-ng/logs/incoming_all.log"); };
destination d_OUTGOING_ISERIES   { file("/app/syslog-ng/logs/outgoing_iseries.log"); };
destination d_olivier2 { file ("/app/syslog-ng/logs/test_olivier2.log" template("host=${HOST} message=${MESSAGE}\n") ); };

filter f_is_iSeries {
  match ("PowerTech.*Interact" value("MESSAGE") flags(ignore-case));
};

filter f_is_Network     {
  host("cswc.*" flags(ignore-case))
  or program("raslogd" flags(ignore-case));
};

# -------- not working anymore
log {
 source(s_EXTERNAL);
 filter(f_is_iSeries);
 destination(d_OUTGOING_ISERIES);
 flags(final);
};

# ------- working now
log {
 source(s_EXTERNAL_NOPARSE);
 junction {
    channel {
            filter(f_is_Network);
    };
 };
 destination(d_olivier2);
};
```

i can now see this log in the test d_olivier2 dest :

```
[root@xm3p1034vmo etc]# cat ../logs/test_olivier2.log
host=cswc-mo8x-hpsan01 message=<190>raslogd: 2017/03/23-16:29:44, [SEC-1203], 53656, WWN 10:00:50:eb:1a:6c:21:38 | FID 128, INFO, cswc-mo8x-SAN01, Login information: Login successful via TELNET/SSH/RSH. IP Addr: 1.2.3.4
```

but nothing in **/app/syslog-ng/logs/outgoing_iseries.log** :(

Comment: Hi, you cannot have two sources on the same port (except if one source uses udp, and the other tcp). Junctions were developed to solve this problem, and the point is to have more than one channels in them, like in the example in the docs. Now you have only one channel that processes the problematic logs. Add another channel with a filter that selects the other logs, and include the syslog parser to properly parse these messages.

Comment: ok I get it, thanks.
but the thing is, if I add a second channel processing the good logs, i'll have to rewrite all filters I suppose ? as the messages will come reformatted by syslog ?

Comment: No, the syslog-parser is what makes the filters work in the first place. By default, syslog-ng parses every incoming log message using the syslog-parser. The problem is that your switches send malformed messages, that's why you need all these configuration tricks (disable parsing, separate the good and the bad logs, and parse the good logs).